# Weak limits and computing the Fourier transform of the Heaviside function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

A common problem on this site is to compute the Fourier transform of the Heaviside function that is $0$ on the negative reals and $1$ on the positive reals. A standard technique is to consider the approximations $H_\alpha(x)$ defined to be $0$ on the negative reals and $e^{-\alpha x}$ on the positive reals. We then compute the Fourier transform and obtain (ignoring a constant factor)
$$\widehat{H_\alpha}(w) = \frac{1}{\alpha + iw}.$$

[One can show that taking the limit as $\alpha$ goes to zero gives the correct answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122220/clear-explanation-of-heaviside-function-fourier-transform)

I am uncomfortable with one part of this argument. We are claiming that since $H_\alpha\rightarrow H$ as distributions, $\widehat{H_\alpha}\rightarrow \widehat H$. On one hand, this seems true because $\widehat H_\alpha(\phi)=H(\hat{\phi})$, so just staring at the definitions seems to prove it. On the other hand, I am having trouble making sense of the following computation.

Let's consider approximating $H$ a different way, using the characteristic functions of the interval $[0,M]$. We should obtain
$$\widehat H(w) = \lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^M e^{-iwt} \ dt = \lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1-e^{iwM}}{iw}.$$

But this limit does not appear to be $\hat H$. In fact, it doesn't seem to exist.

What is going on here? If my reasoning is correct, how can one show the latter limit gives the right answer?

Comment: Please note that you've forgotten a "$-$" in the exponent after integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter limit does not exist because you think about it *pointwisely*. Instead, you should check the limit in the *topology of tempered distributions*, where it will be seen to exist and be exactly what it should be. To this end, pick $\varphi \in \mathcal S(\Bbb R)$ and check whether (I'm omitting multiplicative constant factors) $\lim \limits _{M \to \infty} \langle \frac {1 - \Bbb e ^{-\Bbb i w m}} {\Bbb i w}, \varphi \rangle = \langle \frac 1 {\Bbb i w}, \varphi \rangle$, i.e. whether $\lim \limits _{M \to \infty} \int \limits _{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac {\Bbb e ^{-\Bbb i wM}} w \varphi \Bbb d w = 0$. Now, I'm writing in a rush, please check whether the following is right.

Let $I(M) = \int \limits _{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac {\Bbb e ^{-\Bbb i wM}} w \varphi \Bbb d w$, so $I'(M) = \int \limits _{-\infty} ^{\infty} \Bbb e ^{-\Bbb i wM} \varphi \Bbb d w = \hat \varphi (M)$, so $I(M) = \int \limits _0 ^M \hat \varphi (t) \Bbb d t = \int \limits _0 ^1 \hat \varphi (Mu) M \Bbb d u$. It is known that the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is again a Schwartz function, therefore $\hat \varphi$ decreases rapidly towards infinity, so a combination of this fact and of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem shows that $I(M) \to 0$ as desired, saving the coherence of mathematics once more!