# What's the Fourier transform of these functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

1. The Fourier transform of $|x|^{\alpha}$.

   This is the Fourier transform of a homogeneous function, and there are several cases of various $\alpha$: when $a\leq -n$, it's not a temperate distribution; when $-n<\alpha<0$,then the Fourier transform is $c_{n}|\xi|^{-n+\alpha}$, where $c_{n}$ is some constant; when $\alpha=2k$,a positive even number, then it's Fourier transformation is $(-\Delta)^{k}\delta_{0}$.

   My question is when $\alpha$ is any positive number (not the even case), then what's the Fourier transform of it ?
2. The Fourier transform of $e^{it|x|}$ ?

   (the Fourier transforms I have mentioned here are in the sense of temperate distributions)

Comment: What is $n$? (need more characters)

Comment: n is the dimension of the space

Comment: For $|x|^\alpha$, see [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-log-x-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943).

Answer (score 8):

${1.} $ The corresponding operator is denoted $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ and is called [fractional Laplacian](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_Laplacian). Basically the Fourier transform of $|x|^\alpha$ "should be" a homogeneous function $|\xi|^{-n-\alpha}$. Since it is not locally summable it is not a kernel of an integral operator. But it defines an elliptic linear integro-differential operator of order $\alpha$. For $0<\alpha<2$
$$
(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} u(x) = -c_{n,\alpha} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{u(x-y)-2u(x)+u(x+y) }{|y|^{n+\alpha}}dy.
$$

One-dimensional analogue can be this. Function $|x|^{-1}$  is not locally summable and thus doesn't define a regular distribution. But it can be used to define  a distribution as
$$
({\cal P}\frac1{|x|},\varphi)=
\int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|}\,dx+
\int_{|x|> 1}\frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|}\,dx.
$$