# Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I want to find the fourier transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$. I checked the table of common fourier transforms in Wikipedia, and I know the answer should be $$\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{|\omega|}}$$

What I can't find out, however, is *why* that is the answer.

I tried 
$$ \hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}} e^{-i\omega x} dx$$
$$ = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} e^{-i\omega x} dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} e^{i\omega x} dx$$

but that just gives me two unsolvable exponential integrals.

I also tried finding the answer through residue calculus, as the function has a single singularity at 0, which yields

$$ \hat{f}(\omega) = 2\pi i \ Res_{z = 0} \frac{e^{-i \omega z}}{\sqrt{|z|}} = 2\pi i \lim_{z \to 0} (e^{-i \omega z}) = 2\pi i$$

What am I doing wrong? Or am I thinking completely in the wrong direction?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the Fourier transform of a distribution.

Comment: In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943), I found the Fourier transform of $|x|^s$ for all real values of $s$, positive and negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the change of variables $x=t^2$ in both integrals in $\hat f(\omega)$ and use parity to extend the limits of integration to $-\infty$ and $\infty$.

Things will then become much more clear.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot, but I must be missing something obvious. I tried to extend the limits, but I get $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2 cos(x^2)}{x} dx$, which does not converge. Could you elaborate on extending the limits?

Comment: @TiamoP. Please check your calculations, there is no $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I forgot an $x$ on substitution. Thanks, I understand now!

Comment: In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943), I found the Fourier transform of $|x|^s$ for all real values of $s$, positive and negative.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffd,5px]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{-\ic\omega x} \over \root{\verts{x}}}\,\dd x} =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\verts{\omega}x} \over \root{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\verts{\omega}x\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,&
{2 \over \root{\verts{\omega}}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{x} \over \root{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]
\stackrel{\root{x}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,&
{4 \over \root{\verts{\omega}}}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\pars{x^{2}}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{{\root{2\pi} \over 4}}}
\\ = &\
\bbx{\root{2\pi} \over \root{\verts{\omega}}}
\\ &
\end{align}
The *last integral* is a
[Fresnel Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Limits_as_x_approaches_infinity).

Comment: Hello my friend.  How have you been?  In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943), I found the Fourier transform of $|x|^s$ for all real values of $s$, positive and negative.

Comment: @MarkViola Everything is 0 k. over here -in Florida- I’ll see your answer.

Comment: Ah.  You're in Florida now.  What are you doing there, if I may ask?

Answer (score 3):

Apart from potentially interesting and compelling heuristics, the *literal* integrals for Fourier transforms do not converge at all for such functions. But that's ok, because the Fourier transform extends to tempered distributions *not* by the literal integral description, but by an extension-by-continuity in the dual topology to Schwartz functions (which is quite weak, and does not refer at all to pointwise convergence of integrals).

Even better than just looking at weak-dual limits is to look at the *properties* of functions such as $|x|^s$. They are *homogeneous*. It is easy to show that Fourier transform converts homogeneous tempered *distributions* of degree $s$ to homogeneous tempered distributions of degree $1-s$ (up to normalizations and conventions...). So the only question is to determine the constant, which can be done by applying the functional(s) to things like Gaussians or Gaussians multiplied by $x$...

EDIT: as noted by @F.H. in a comment, the Fourier transform is homogeneous of degree $-1-s$, not $1-s$.

Comment: You mean degree $-1-s$.

Comment: @F.H., oops, yes, thanks...