# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty{\frac{\ln x \sin x}{x}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Evaluate$$\int_0^\infty{\frac{\ln x \sin x}{x}dx}$$
I don't know where to start with this integral. Mathematica shows that $-\frac{\gamma\pi}2$ is the answer, so I don't think that it is easy to be solved.

Comment: Maybe you could use Feynmans technique on $I(a) =\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\ln(ax)}{x}\,dx$

Comment: Use differentiation under the integral sign and the imaginary part of$$I=\lim\limits_{a\to 0}\frac {\partial}{\partial a}\int\limits_0^{\infty}dx\, x^{a-1}e^{ix}$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward: the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) of $\sin(x)$ is $\frac{1}{s^2+1}$ and the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is $-\gamma-\log(s)$, hence
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)\sin(x)}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{-\gamma-\log(s)}{1+s^2}\,ds = -\frac{\gamma\pi}{2} $$
since $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log s}{1+s^2}\,ds$ vanishes by symmetry ($s\mapsto \frac{1}{s}$).

Comment: Can you explain please how to compute the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\log x}{x}$ ?

Comment: @Zacky: the Laplace transform of $\log(x)$ is straightforward to compute by differentiation under the integral sign. Keep $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$ into consideration and invert.

Answer (score 9):

> I thought it might be instructive to present another approach that uses real analysis only, which complement my answer using contour integration ([SEE THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733923/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-ln-x-sin-xxdx/2734247#2734247)).  We shall make use of Frullani's integral.  To that end we proceed.

---

Note that from Frullani's Integral we have

$$\log(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t}\,dt\tag1$$

---

Using $(1)$, we can write the integral of interest as

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)\sin(x)}{x}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t}\,dt\right) \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac1t \color{blue}{\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}(e^{-t}-e^{-xt})\,dx} \,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac1t\color{blue}{\left(\frac\pi2e^{-t}-\pi/2+\arctan(t)\right)}\,dt\tag2
\end{align}$$

---

Integrating by parts the integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ with $u=\frac\pi2e^{-t}-\pi/2+\arctan(t)$ and $v=\frac1t$ reveal

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac1t\color{blue}{\left(\frac\pi2e^{-t}-\pi/2+\arctan(t)\right)}\,dt&=-\int_0^\infty \log(t)\color{blue}{\left(-\frac\pi2 e^{-t}+\frac1{t^2+1}\right)}\,dt\\\\
&=-\frac\pi2\gamma
\end{align}$$

since $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(t)}{t^2+1}\,dt\overbrace{=}^{t\mapsto1/t}\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(1/t)}{t^2+1}\,dt\implies \int_0^\infty \frac{\log(t)}{t^2+1}\,dt=0$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Indeed.  I am only of Italian descent as my Great Grandparents emigrated to the US from Italy.

Comment: @MarkViola Hi Mark. Why don't the boundary contributions from the $\frac{\pi}{2}log(t)$ term matter in the integration by parts?

Comment: @ki3i Hi.   The boundary terms vanish since $\lim_{t\to 0}t\log(t)=0$.

Comment: @MarkViola Oh...since $e^{-t}-1\sim -t+o(t)$ near $0$? And, $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \log(t)e^{-t}=0$ for the contributions at large $t$?

Comment: Yes.  And don't forget $\pi/2-\arctan(t)=\arctan(1/t)\sim \frac1t$ as $t\to \infty$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty }\frac{\log(t)}{t}=0$.

Comment: @MarkViola indeed, thanks! :-)

Comment: @ki3i You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

> I wanted to present a way forward using contour integration that is complementary to the real analysis solution I presented earlier [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733923/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-ln-x-sin-xxdx/2734122#2734122).  To the end, we proceed.

---

Using the principal value of the complex logarithm, Cauchy's Integral Theorem Guarantees that for $0<\epsilon<R$

$$\begin{align}
0&=\int_\epsilon^R \frac{e^{ix}\log(x)}{x}\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{iRe^{i\phi}}\log(Re^{i\phi})}{Re^{i\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_R^\epsilon \frac{e^{-x}\log(ix)}{ix}\,i\,dx+\int_{\pi/2}^0\frac{e^{i\epsilon e^{i\phi}}\log(\epsilon e^{i\phi})}{\epsilon e^{i\phi}}\,i\epsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\tag 1
\end{align}$$

---

For the second integral on the right-and side of $(1)$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{iRe^{i\phi}}\log(Re^{i\phi})}{Re^{i\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\right|&\le \int_0^{\pi/2}|\log(R)+i\phi|e^{-R\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi\\\\
&\le (\log(R)+\pi/2) \int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-2R\phi/\pi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=(\log(R)+\pi/2) \left(\frac{1-e^{-R}}{2R/\pi}\right)\tag2
\end{align}$$

which clearly vanishes in the limit as $R\to\infty$.

---

For the fourth integral on the right-and side of $(1)$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\text{Im}\left(\int_{\pi/2}^0\frac{e^{i\epsilon e^{i\phi}}\log(\epsilon e^{i\phi})}{\epsilon e^{i\phi}}\,i\epsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\right)&=-\frac\pi2\log(\epsilon)+O(\epsilon\log(\epsilon))\tag3
\end{align}$$

---

Hence, taking the imaginary part of $(1)$ and letting $R\to \infty$ and $\epsilon\to 0$ and using $(2)$ and $(3)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)\sin(x)}{x}\,dx= \frac\pi2 \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx +\log(\epsilon)\right)\tag4
\end{align}$$

Finally, integrating by parts the integral on the right-hand side of $(4)$ with $u=e^{-x}$ and $v=\log(x)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)\sin(x)}{x}\,dx&=\frac\pi2\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(-e^{-\epsilon}\log(\epsilon)+\int_\epsilon^\infty \log(x)e^{-x}\,dx+\log(\epsilon)\right)\\\\
&=\frac\pi2 \int_0^\infty \log(x)e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac\pi2\gamma
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Another great answer! (+1) I need to properly learn complex analysis, turns out my mistake was caused by the lack of knowledge in this area

Comment: Thank you Yuriy!

Comment: Excellent, big (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a full answer, but if you treat this integral as the Mellin transform (from $x$ to $s$) of $\log(x)\sin(x)$, Mathematica gives the result, 
$$
\mathcal{M}_{x\to s}[\log(x) \sin(x)] = \frac{\pi}{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(s) + \Gamma(s) \psi_0(s)\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)
$$
this can be found on page 318 (pdf page 330), under entry (13), of [this book](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf). When $s=0$, we reclaim the integral you had, but this result diverges. If we take the limit $s \to 0$, we get $-\frac{\gamma \pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

An attempt on a more self-contained solution (within reason of course).

Let's write the integral as:

$$I=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \ln x \sin x e^{-a x} da dx$$

Let's reverse the order of integration and find:

$$I_1=\int_0^\infty \ln x \sin x e^{-a x} dx$$

Using the exponential form of $\sin x$, we have:

$$I_1=\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty \ln x \left( e^{-(a-i) x}-e^{-(a+i) x}\right)dx$$

Let's find a general integral of the form:

$$\int_0^\infty \ln x e^{-b x}dx=\frac{1}{b} \int_0^\infty \ln x e^{-x}dx-\frac{\ln b}{b} \int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx=$$

$$=\color{blue}{-\frac{\gamma}{b}-\frac{\ln b}{b}}$$

Where the integral formula first proved by Euler is used for the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Now let's deal with our particular parameters. The first term will be:

$$-\frac{\gamma}{2i} \left(\frac{1}{a-i}-\frac{1}{a+i} \right)=-\color{blue}{\frac{\gamma}{1+a^2}}$$

The second term is a little more complicated:

$$-\frac{1}{2i} \left(\frac{\ln (a-i)}{a-i}-\frac{\ln (a+i)}{a+i} \right)=-\frac{1}{2i(1+a^2)} \left(a \ln \frac{a-i}{a+i}+i \ln (1+a^2)\right)$$

With a little care we can show:

### $$\ln \frac{a-i}{a+i}=\ln \left( \frac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}-\frac{2a}{a^2+1}i \right)=\begin{cases} -i \arcsin \frac{2a}{1+a^2} & |a| \geq 1 \\ i \arcsin \frac{2a}{1+a^2}-i \pi  & |a| < 1 \end{cases}$$

Finally we have:

> $$I_1=-\frac{\gamma}{1+a^2}-\frac{\ln (1+a^2)}{2(1+a^2)} +\frac{a}{2(1+a^2)} \arcsin \frac{2a}{1+a^2}, \qquad a\geq 1$$
>
> $$I_1=-\frac{\gamma}{1+a^2}-\frac{\ln (1+a^2)}{2(1+a^2)} -\frac{a}{2(1+a^2)} \arcsin \frac{2a}{1+a^2}+\frac{ \pi a}{2(1+a^2)}, \qquad a<1$$

---

To find the original integral we need to integrate w.r.t. $a$:

$$I=\int_0^\infty I_1(a) da$$

---

The first term alredy gives the correct answer:

$$-\gamma \int_0^\infty \frac{da}{1+a^2}=-\frac{\gamma \pi}{2}$$

> $$\color{blue}{I=-\frac{\gamma \pi}{2}}$$

---

The **rest of the post is an addendum** to show that the other terms give $0$ after integration.

First, we deal with the $\arcsin $ integrals:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{a}{1+a^2} \arcsin \frac{2a}{1+a^2} da=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{b^3 (1+1/b^2)} \arcsin \frac{2}{b(1+1/b^2)} db$$

$$=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{b (1+b^2)} \arcsin \frac{2b}{1+b^2} db$$

So:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_1^\infty \frac{a}{1+a^2} \arcsin \frac{2a}{1+a^2} da-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{a}{1+a^2} \arcsin \frac{2a}{1+a^2} da= $$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^\infty \frac{a^2-1}{a (a^2+1)} \arccos \frac{a^2-1}{a^2+1} da=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{y \arccos y~ dy}{1-y^2} =$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan s~ ds}{s(1+s^2)}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{dt ds}{(1+s^2)(1+t^2 s^2)}=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{t dt ds}{(t^2+s^2)(1+s^2)}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{t s^2 dt ds}{(1+t^2s^2)(1+s^2)}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (1+s^2)}{1+s^2}ds$$

Now we only need to find the logarithmic integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (1+a^2)}{1+a^2}da=\frac{1}{2} \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln u}{u \sqrt{u-1}}du= $$

$$=-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln u}{\sqrt{u} \sqrt{1-u}}du=-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \ln u ~u^{a-1} (1-u)^{-1/2}du \bigg|_{a=1/2}$$

Consider:

$$\int_0^1 u^{a-1} (1-u)^{-1/2}du=B \left( \frac{1}{2},a \right)=\frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)\Gamma \left( a \right)}{\Gamma  \left( \frac{1}{2}+a \right)}$$

The derivative is expressed through digamma function:

$$\int_0^1 \ln u ~u^{a-1} (1-u)^{-1/2}du= \left( \psi \left( a \right)-\psi  \left( a +\frac{1}{2}\right)  \right) B \left( \frac{1}{2},a \right)$$

So we have:

$$\int_0^1 \ln u ~u^{-1/2} (1-u)^{-1/2}du=\left( \psi \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)-\psi  \left( 1\right)  \right) \pi=- \pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n-1)}$$

And finally:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (1+a^2)}{1+a^2}da=\pi \ln 2$$

We also have:

$$\frac{ \pi }{2} \int_0^1 \frac{ a da}{1+a^2}=\frac{\pi \ln 2}{4} $$

Adding all the terms we obtain $0$, as it should be.