# Do functions exist, for which the the cosine transform does not exist, but the sine transform exists?

Tags: fourier-transform

Is there a real valued function

$f: (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

s.th.

$\int_{0}^\infty \cos(kx) f(x) dx$

does not exist as a reasonable function/distribution, but

$\int_{0}^\infty \sin(kx) f(x) dx$

exists (or vice versa)?

Comment: Try $f(x)=x^{-(1+\alpha)}$ for $\alpha\in(0,1)$?

Comment: @Feng The Fourier transform as a distribution exists for all $|x|^s$.  See [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943).  Therefore, both the sine and cosine transforms exist.

Comment: @MarkViola Of course. I thought OP was concerning something like the convergence of improper integral. Thanks for your reply! Btw, nice answer :)

Comment: @Feng Indeed.  The OP might have been considering functions under the PV distribution   in the sense of improper Riemann integrals.  And thank you for the nice comment.