# Fourier transform of hyperbolic functions

Tags: fourier-transform

I am looking for the Fourier transform of $x \tanh(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. The Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is $$2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)\exp\left(-(2n+1)\frac{|t|}{2}\right).$$ But there is singularity at $0$. How can I get
the Fourier transform of $x \tanh(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I revised your post for spelling, grammar, LaTeX issues, and removing casual words like "hi." All of these things are standard on this site, and you should familiarize yourself with the rules and expectations surrounding asking a good question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

There are still some things you can do to improve this question further, such as providing the source of the question and your own efforts.

Comment: Since $x \tanh(x)$ is an even function of $x$ you can just evaluate your series as $$2 \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty } (2 n+1) \exp \left(-(2 n+1)\, \frac{t}{2}\right)=\coth\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\, \text{csch}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$$ and $\underset{t\to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(\coth\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\, \text{csch}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)=\infty$.

Comment: @StevenClark That expression is not the Fourier Transform of the Tempered Distribution $x\tanh(x)$.

Comment: @rim Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fourier Transform of the distribution $t\tanh(t)$ is a tempered distribution.  We can calculate its Fourier Transform in terms of the sum of the Fourier tranform of the $L^1$ funcion $f(t)=t\tanh(t)-|t|$ and the Fourier Transform of the tempered distribution $g(t)=|t|$.  We now proceed.

---

---

**FOURIER TRANSFORM OF $\displaystyle |t|$:**

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943), I developed the Fourier Transform for $g_a(t)=|t|^a$ for all real values of $a$.  In particular, for $a=1$, we have

$$\mathscr{F}\{ g_1\}(\omega)=-\frac2{\omega^2}$$

Note that the object $\mathscr{F}\{ g_1\}(\omega)=-2/\omega^2$ is not a function; it is a Tempered distribution.  It does not assign a value  for each $\omega$.  Rather, it is defined as how it acts on any Schwartz function $\phi$ in the following way.  We have

$$\langle \mathscr{F}\{ g_1\},\phi\rangle =\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_{|\omega|\ge\delta|} \left(\frac{-2}{\omega^2}\right)\left(\phi(\omega)-\phi(0)\right)\,d\omega $$

---

---

**FOURIER TRANSFORM OF $\displaystyle \tanh(t)-|t|$:**

Note that the function $f(t)=\tanh(t)-|t|$ is in $L^1$.  Therefore, its Fourier Transform is given by

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\omega)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \left(t\tanh(t)-|t|\right)\,e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty t(\tanh(t) - 1)\cos(\omega t)\,dt\\\\
&=4\int_0^\infty t\left(\frac{e^{-2t}}{1+e^{-2t}}\right)\cos(\omega t)\,dt\\\\
&=4\frac{d}{d\omega}\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{e^{-2t}}{1+e^{-2t}}\right)\sin(\omega t)\,dt\\\\
&=4\frac{d}{d\omega}\Im\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{e^{-(2t-i\omega)t}}{1+e^{-2t}}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=4\frac{d}{d\omega}\Im\int_0^\infty e^{-(2t-i\omega)t} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^ne^{-2nt}\,dt\\\\
&=4\frac{d}{d\omega}\Im\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int_0^\infty e^{-(2t-i\omega)t} e^{-2nt}\,dt\\\\
&=4\frac{d}{d\omega}\Im\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{2(n+1)-i\omega}\\\\
&=4\frac{d}{d\omega}\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n\omega }{4(n+1)^2+\omega^2} \\\\
&=\frac{d}{d\omega}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\omega}{n^2+(\omega/2)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{d}{d\omega}\frac{\pi \omega \,\operatorname{csch}(\pi \omega/2)-2}{\omega}\\\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}2 \frac{\cosh(\pi \omega /2)}{\sinh^2(\pi \omega/2)}+\frac2{\omega^2}
\end{align}$$

where we exploited the partial fraction representation of the hyperbolic cosecant function given by

$$\operatorname{csch}(z)=\frac1z +2z\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n\pi)^2+z^2}$$

The value of the Fourier Transform of $f$ at $\omega=0$ is equal to $-\pi^2/12$.

---

---

Putting it all together, we find that the Fourier Transform of $t\tanh(t)$ is the tempered distribution

$$\mathscr{F}\{|f|\}(\omega)=-\frac{\pi^2}2 \frac{\cosh(\pi \omega /2)}{\sinh^2(\pi \omega/2)}$$

where (again), the object $\mathscr{F}\{|f|\}(\omega)$ is defined as a Tempered Distribution.  Therefore, for any Schwartz Function $\phi$, we have

$$\langle \mathscr{F}\{|f|\}, \phi\rangle =\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\int_{|\omega|\ge\delta} \left(-\frac{\pi^2}2 \frac{\cosh(\pi \omega /2)}{\sinh^2(\pi \omega/2)}\right)(\phi(\omega)-\phi(0))\,d\omega$$

Comment: actually i try to understand why there is problem at 0?

Comment: The integral $\int_{-\infty} t\tanh(t) e^{i\omega t}\,dt$ does not exist for any value of $\omega$.  However, the Fourier Transform of $t\tanh(t)$ does exist as a Tempered Disrtibution.  We note that the Fourier Transform of the function $t\tanh(t)-|t|$ does exist as the integral $$\int_{-\infty} \left(t\tanh(t)-|t|\right) e^{i\omega t}\,dt$$In fact, when $\omega =0$, its value is $-\pi^2/12$.  However, the Fourier Transform of $|t|$ exists as the Tempered Distribution $-2/\omega^2$, which has no value at $\omega=0$.  See the answer I referenced for more details.  Does that clarify?

Comment: @ Mark Viola yes thank you

Comment: @rim You're welcome.   My pleasure

Comment: @Mark Viola just for curiosity the transform of fourier of  f in $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}is given if i wanted to  prove it,how can i do that ?

Comment: @rim The Fourier Transform of $|t|$ exists only as a tempered distribution.   It does not exist as an $L^1$ integration.   It is NOT equal to the ordinary function $-2/\omega^2$.  It is equal to the Tempered Distribution $-2/\omega^2$.  The same applies to $f$

Comment: yes as a tempered distribution how can i show that   fourier  transform  of$f(x)= xtanh(x)$ coincides in   $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$  with the function g(t)=$2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)\exp\left(-(2n+1)\frac{|t|}{2}\right)$?

Comment: @rim What do you think is the closed-form for that series when $t\ne0$?

Comment: its the derivative of $-4\sum_{k=0,k even}^{\infty}\exp(-\frac{(k-1)|t|}{2})$ ?

Comment: but i dont think that it will provide an additional information –(even if i take inverse fourier transform i will not have the result)

Comment: @rim What result do you mean?  I've tried to explain that the FT here is not defined as an integral.

Comment: yes i understood that , to answer your question the closest form of that series is $-4\frac{dt}{dt}\sum_{k=0,even}\exp(-\frac{(k-1)|t|}{2}$but can that give me that the series coincides with fourier transform of f?

Comment: HI Mark Viola ,its given in the exercice(the series)