# Fourier transform for $H(t)$ and test function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let $$H(t) = \begin{cases}  1 & t\gt0 \\ 0 & t\lt 0\end{cases}$$ I'm trying to find Fourier transform of $H(t).$ So we have $$\mathcal{F}\{H(t)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-j\omega t}dt$$
Obviously this integral doesn't converge. So there are some ways to make this integral meaningful like introducing a damping factor. According to what I know from the distribution theory, If we want to view that as a distribution, we should see what happens when it acts on a test function $\phi(\omega)$. Then $$I =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(\omega)\phi(\omega)d\omega = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt\phi(\omega)d\omega = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(t)\phi(\omega)e^{-j\omega t}dtd\omega$$ Assuming changing order of integration is valid $$I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(t)\phi(\omega)e^{-j\omega t}d\omega dt= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(t)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(\omega)e^{-j\omega t}d\omega dt$$ 
And I'm stuck here. The answer should be $$H(\omega) = \frac{1}{j\omega} + \pi\delta(\omega)$$I've seen many other pages on MSE related to this problem but didn't found an answer which continues my approach. Maybe I'm totally wrong?

Also in the distributional sense, it has been proved that $$H(\omega) = \pi \delta(\omega) + \mathrm{P} \frac{1}{j\omega}$$
So we have $\mathrm{P} \frac{1}{j\omega} = \frac{1}{j\omega}$?

Comment: Does $P$ denotes the principal value? Then notice that $1/{j\omega}$ is not locally integrable so not a distribution! You cannot use this function if you are working with generalized Fourier transform. In the world of distribution, the only object that makes sense is the principal value of $1/{j\omega}$, and I suppose people from physics will just write $1/{j\omega}$.

Comment: @LL3.14 Yes, it does. It comes from a "Signals and Systems" course. So using $1/j\omega$ is wrong?

Comment: Rigourosly, yes. But it is not wrong if you know that you are talking about distributions, and so about the principal value. This is just a notation.

Comment: @LL3.14 I've seen some derivations which treats that really like $1/j\omega$(for example they simply multiply by $1/j\omega$). I don't know how it's possible to make them rigorous.

Comment: You have $j\omega P (1/j\omega) = 1$ in the sense of distributions. But the better is to look at any course of Fourier theory for distributions.

Comment: @LL3.14 Thanks a lot for your help. Do you have any idea how can I proceed with the mentioned integral?

Comment: Partial answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1186815

Comment: @pluton Thanks but actually I need an answer which explains things more because this is really unknown territory for me.

Comment: You can try the following: $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(t)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(\omega)e^{-j\omega t}d\omega dt=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\epsilon t}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(\omega)e^{-j\omega t}d\omega dt\\=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_0^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(\omega)e^{-(j\omega+\epsilon) t}d\omega dt$$ and then use the limiting procedures shown in the above post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will denote the Fourier transform of $f$ by $\widehat{f}$, and I recall that by definition
$$
\langle P(\tfrac{1}{x}),\varphi\rangle = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\varepsilon}\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d} x
$$

So as you write, for any test function $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle\widehat{H},\varphi\rangle &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} H(x)\,\widehat{\varphi}(x)\,\mathrm{d} x
\\
&= \int_0^\infty\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-ixy}\varphi(y)\,\mathrm{d} y\,\mathrm{d}x
\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^n\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-ixy}\varphi(y)\,\mathrm{d} y\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
$$
Since $\varphi$ is compactly supported, there exists $a>0$ such that $\varphi=0$ out of $[-a,a]$, and since $\varphi$ and bounded, $$\int_0^n\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\varphi(y)|\,\mathrm{d} y\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^n\int_{-a}^a |\varphi(y)|\,\mathrm{d} y\,\mathrm{d}x < \infty
$$
so we can use Fubini Theorem to get
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle\widehat{H},\varphi\rangle &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(y) \int_0^n e^{-ixy}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d} y
\\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0,\,n\to\infty} \int_{\varepsilon<|y|} \varphi(y)\, \frac{1-e^{-iny}}{i\,y}\,\mathrm{d} y
\\
&= \langle P(\tfrac{1}{ix}),\varphi\rangle + \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0,\,n\to\infty} \int_{\varepsilon<|y|<a} \varphi(y)\, \frac{-e^{-iny}}{i\,y}\,\mathrm{d} y
\end{align*}
$$
Now remark that by doing the change of variable $y \to -y$ in the second integral when $y<0$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{\varepsilon<|y|<a} \varphi(y)\, \frac{-e^{-iny}}{i\,y}\,\mathrm{d} y &= \int_{\varepsilon<y<a} \frac{\varphi(-y)e^{iny}-\varphi(y)e^{-iny}}{i\,y}\,\mathrm{d} y
\\
&= \int_{\varepsilon<y<a} \frac{(\varphi(-y)-\varphi(0))\,e^{iny}-(\varphi(y)-\varphi(0))e^{-iny}}{i\,y}\,\mathrm{d} y
\\
&\qquad + \varphi(0)\int_{\varepsilon<y<a} \frac{\,e^{iny}-e^{-iny}}{i\,y}\,\mathrm{d} y
\\
&= \int_{\varepsilon<|y|<a} \psi(y)e^{-iny}\,\mathrm{d} y + \varphi(0)\int_{\varepsilon<y<a} \frac{2\sin(ny)}{y}\,\mathrm{d} y
\end{align*}
$$
where $\psi(y) = \frac{\varphi(0)-\varphi(y)}{iy}$ is a smooth function. To conclude remark that with $u = ny$ we get
$$
\int_{\varepsilon<y<a} \frac{2\sin(ny)}{y}\,\mathrm{d} y = \int_{n\varepsilon<u<na} \frac{2\sin(u)}{u}\,\mathrm{d} u \underset{\varepsilon\to 0,\,n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} \int_{0}^\infty \frac{2\sin(u)}{u}\,\mathrm{d} u = \pi
$$
where one should first take the limit in $\varepsilon$ and then in $n$, while by Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{\varepsilon<|y|<a} \psi(y)e^{-iny}\,\mathrm{d} y  = \int_{|y|<a} \psi(y)e^{-iny}\,\mathrm{d} y\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}  0
$$

Therefore
$$\boxed{\langle\widehat{H},\varphi\rangle = \langle P(\tfrac{1}{ix}),\varphi\rangle + \pi\,\varphi(0)}$$
or equivalently, in the sense of distributions, we have the equality
$$
\widehat{H} = P(\tfrac{1}{ix}) + \pi\,\delta_0
$$

Comment: Regarding this limit:
$$
\int_{n\varepsilon<u<na} \frac{2\sin(u)}{u}\,\mathrm{d} u 
\underset{\varepsilon\to 0,\,n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{2\sin(u)}{u}\,\mathrm{d} u
$$
It should be made clear that the limits are in order $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0},$ i.e. first $\epsilon \to 0,$ then $n \to \infty.$ This can be seen at the introduction of the double limit, but it easy to think that the limits are taken at the same time, which could result in $n \epsilon \to a > 0.$

Comment: Yes right, this is why I wrote them in the good order under the arrow (i.e. first do the limit in $\varepsilon$ then in $n$). I will add a precision.

Answer (score 6):

$\def\sign{\operatorname{sign}}$
Let's start with the $\sign$ function:
$$
\sign(x) = \begin{cases}
-1, & (x<0) \\
1, & (x>0) \\
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $\sign' = 2\delta$ and that $\sign$ is odd.

Taking the Fourier transform of $\sign' = 2\delta$ gives $i\xi \, \widehat{\sign}(\xi) = 2.$ Therefore $\widehat{\sign}(\xi) = \frac{2}{i\xi} + C\delta(\xi),$ where $\frac{1}{\xi}$ is the principal value distribution. Since $\sign$ is odd, so must be $\widehat{\sign}$. Therefore $C=0.$ Thus, $\widehat{\sign}(\xi) = \frac{2}{i\xi}.$

Now, $H(x) = \frac12(1+\sign(x))$ so
$$
\hat{H}(\xi) 
= \frac12(\hat{1}(\xi) + \widehat{\sign}(\xi)) 
= \frac12(2\pi\,\delta(\xi) + \frac{2}{i\xi}) 
= \pi\,\delta(\xi) + \frac{1}{i\xi}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. Your approach looks interesting but could you help me to continue the mentioned approach, please? I mean what's the next step after $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(t)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(\omega)e^{-j\omega t}d\omega dt$?

Answer (score 3):

As $r\to 0^+$, $$e^{-rt}1_{t >0}\to 1_{t>0}$$ in the sense of tempered distributions thus taking the Fourier of both side $$\frac1{r+i\omega}\to \widehat{1_{t >0}}$$
$\frac1{r+i\omega}$ is the distributional derivative of $-i\log(\omega-ir)$ and in $L^1_{loc}$ thus in the sense of distributions $$-i\log(\omega-ir)\to -i\log |\omega|-\pi 1_{\omega <0}$$

Thus, taking the distributional derivative of both side $$\frac1{r+i\omega}\to pv(\frac1{i\omega})+\pi\delta(\omega)$$

ie. $$\widehat{1_{t >0}}=pv(\frac1{i\omega})+\pi\delta(\omega)$$

Comment: Equivalently replace $\phi$ by $\phi e^{-rt}1_{t > -A}$ in your question before changing the order of summation and let $r\to 0$ at the end.

Comment: I like this approach, first time I see it!

Answer (score -1):

Your test-function approach is correct as your guess, maybe with some constant factor distinct due to the $2\pi$ factor on the corresponding Fourier Transform definition you are using.

A year or two ago I was dealing with the same question and found [The Fourier transform of the Heaviside function](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/~bueler/M611heaviside.pdf) explaniation, not bad.

I hope this link still helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help but that doesn't really answer my question. Surely it's an interesting approach.