# Need help with Fourier transform problem

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the Fourier transform of the unit step function,

$$\mathcal{F}[u(t)] \ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt \ = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-i\omega t} dt. \tag{1}$$

This simplifies to,

$$U(\omega) = (i\omega)^{-1},\ (\omega \not = 0). \tag{2}$$

However, my book claims that $(1)$ simplifies to $ \pi \delta(\omega) + (i\omega)^{-1}. \tag{3}$

Here, $\delta(\omega)$ is the unit impulse function. I don't have my book with me right now but I think they use the differentiation property to derive it by calculating the transform of the derivative of $u$ (which is $\delta$).

My question is, isn't the appearance of $\delta$ in the result they obtain irrelevant? Since, at $\omega  = 0$, $(3) = \infty$ and elsewhere $(3) = (2).$ So, why would they write $(3)$ instead of $(2)$? I should mention this is not in a mathematics textbook, but an engineering textbook.

Comment: How do you get (2) from (1)?

Comment: @Artem: consider $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_0^{\infty} dt\, e^{-\epsilon t} \, e^{-i \omega t}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get a delta function is because the step function is actually defined as

$$\theta(t) = \begin{cases} \\ 1 & t \gt 0\\1/2 & t=0\\0 & t \lt 0\end{cases}$$

That nonzero value at $t=0$ is a bit troublesome.  Better to consider the signum funciton $\text{sgn}(t) = 2 \theta(t)-1$.  The FT of $\text{sgn}(t)$ is

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-i \omega t} - \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{i \omega t} = \frac{2}{i \omega}$$

Note that the value at $t=0$, being zero, does not contribute to the FT.  The FT of $\theta(t)$ follows from this, because

$$\theta(t) =  \frac12 \text{sgn}(t) + \frac12$$

so that its FT is

$$\frac{1}{i \omega} + \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \, e^{-i \omega t} = \frac{1}{i \omega} + \pi \delta(\omega)$$

Comment: Could you explain how you evaluated the second integral for $\mathcal{F}[\text{sgn}(t)]$?

Comment: Just substitution $t \rightarrow -t$, so that  $$\int_{-\infty}^0 dt \, e^{-i\omega t}=\int_0^{\infty} dt\,e^{i \omega t}$$

Comment: Yes, then $$\int_0^\infty dt e^{i\omega t} = \left .(i\omega)^{-1} e^{i\omega t} \right |_0^\infty = \infty - (i\omega)^{-1}, (\omega \not = 0).$$ Is that correct?
I'm not sure what $\infty - (i\omega)^{-1}$ evaluates to, or even if I should get that since since $e^{i\omega \infty}$ seems to be undefined because of the $i$.

Comment: The integral is defined in the following sense: $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-\epsilon t} e^{i \omega t}$$

Comment: I'm not really sure how this stands from a rigorous perspective. To evaluate your latest integral, $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-\epsilon t} e^{i \omega t} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left [(i\omega - \epsilon )^{-1} (e^{i\omega t}) \left .\right |_0^\infty\right ] = (e^{i\omega t}) \left .\right |_0^\infty \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left [(i\omega - \epsilon )^{-1} \right ] = (e^{i \omega \infty} - 1) \cdot (i\omega)^{-1}.$$

How may I simplify the last expression? I'm not sure what expressions of the form "$\pm i\infty$" mean.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId: that's not right.  The integral I posted is simply $$\frac{1}{\epsilon-i \omega}$$

Comment: I made a mistake. After doing it again, I get $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-\epsilon t} e^{i \omega t} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left [-(\epsilon - i\omega)^{-1} (e^{-(\epsilon - i\omega) t}) \left .\right |_0^\infty\right ] = (e^{-(\epsilon - i\omega) t}) \left .\right |_0^\infty \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left [-(\epsilon - i\omega)^{-1} \right ] = (0 - 1) \cdot (i\omega)^{-1} = -(i\omega)^{-1}$$

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId: that's more like it.  And that's why the above analysis makes sense.

Comment: Ah, I see. The rest works out just the same. I must say, it was very clever of you to define the integral in that way. I just wish they did that in my engineering book too! Haha

Comment: I'm still not sure about how the $\pi \delta (\omega)$ helps. Since at $\omega = 0$, from my OP, $(3) = \pi - i \infty$ (which I'm not even sure how to define); and, for $\omega \not = 0, (3) = (2).$ Since you're an engineer, do you know how the expression $(3)$ is useful over $(2)$ in light of the above? I am really grateful for all your time on this.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId: it's not a question of being more useful - that's the answer.  We typically do not evaluate delta functions - they end up being used for the sifting property.

Comment: Many thanks for everything.

Comment: @RonGordon Hi Ron, my friend.  I hope that you're doing well and staying safe and healthy.   I've posted a solution [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/fourier-transform-of-unit-step/4111722#4111722) that provide a rigorous methodology to evaluate the Fourier Transform of the unit step function.  As always, I'd appreciate your feedback.