# Fourier transform of the Heaviside function

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

As you can see from the title I want to calculate the Fourier transform of the Heaviside function $u(t)$.
Proven the the Heaviside function is a tempered distribution I must evaluate:

$$ \langle F(u(t)), \varphi \rangle \qquad \varphi \in S_{\xi} $$

Then I use the following property of the Fourier transform:

$$ F(T^{(n)}) = (2 \pi i)^n \xi^n F(T)  $$

In my case, as we have that $u' = \delta$:

$$ F(\delta) =  2 \pi i \xi F(u) $$

In this way I proved that $F(u)$ it's a solution of the following division problem for tempered distribution:

$$ \begin{cases}
\xi T = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \\
T \in S'
\end{cases} $$

If I find another solution of the problem, then the two solution will differ of $c \delta \ , c \in \mathbb{C}$.
Let's prove that $p.v. \frac{1}{2 \pi i \xi}$ it's a solution for the problem.

$$ \langle p.v. \frac{1}{2\pi i \xi}, \varphi\rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\  p.v. \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\xi \varphi(\xi)}{\xi} d\xi = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(\xi) d\xi = \langle \frac{1}{2 \pi i} , \varphi \rangle $$

Then we conclude that:

$$ F(u) = p.v.\ \frac{1}{2\pi i \xi} + c \delta \qquad c \in \mathbb{C} $$

Now, there is the problem. How can I set the value of c ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/fourier-transform-of-unit-step

There are some relevant links in the answers.

Comment: I've already seen the links, but I've only understood intuitively that $c = \frac{1}{2}$, and I don't know how to prove it through my reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know your distribution up to a constant, a good way to fix the constant is to pair the distribution against a test function $f$.
For simplicity, we can pick such an $f$ that both $f$ and $F(f)$ are real and symmetric (a Gaussian, for example).
Now calculate $\langle F(u),{F(f)}\rangle$ in two ways:
$$
\langle F(u),F(f)\rangle
=
p.v.\int\frac1{2\pi i\xi}F(f)(\xi)d\xi+c\langle\delta,F(f)\rangle
=
cF(f)(0)
=
c\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx.
$$
The principal value integral vanishes because $F(f)(\xi)$ is symmetric and $1/\xi$ is antisymmetric.
On the other hand,
$$
\langle F(u),F(f)\rangle
=
\langle u,f\rangle
=
\int_0^\infty f(x)dx
=
\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx.
$$
These two have to be equal, so $c=1/2$.

Note that we did not even need an explicit function $f$, just the knowledge that there is a function with suitable symmetries.
If you prefer something more explicit, you can choose $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Only one question: the integral: $$ p.v \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{F(f)(\xi)}{2 \pi i \xi}\  d\xi $$ It's 0 for the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma ?

Comment: @NunzioDamino, you can't have line breaks in a comment (or at least you can't produce them with enter). I'll add a clarification to my post that was meant to be there in the first place.

Comment: Ok, seems fine to me. Thanks !

Comment: @NunzioDamino, you are welcome! In problems like this, you only need one test function, and with a good choice the calculations are almost trivial. I didn't want to do an integral by hand...