# Convergence Of an Integral.

Tags: improper-integrals, fourier-transform

While finding the Fourier Transform of the unit step function $u(t)$ , I came across the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-i\omega t}dt = \left[-\frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{i \omega}\right]_{0}^{\infty}
$$

The textbook says that the integral will not converge.Can anyone explain the reason why so?

Comment: The issue is that the Fourier Transform of the unit step function is NOT a function.   It is not defined by the integral as written here.  Rather, it is a Tempered Distribution and defined as a functional.  See [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/fourier-transform-of-unit-step/4111722#4111722) for a rigorous development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for a finite upper limit $b$, we have (assuming $w \neq 0$)
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{b}e^{-iwt} dt &= 
\left.-\frac{e^{-iwt}}{iw}\right|_{t=0}^{t=b} \\
& = \frac{1-e^{-iwb}}{iw} \\
&= e^{-iwb/2}\left(\frac{e^{iwb/2} - e^{-iwb/2}}{iw}\right) \\
&= 2e^{-iwb/2}\frac{\sin(wb/2)}{w} \\
\end{aligned}$$
Taking the absolute value, we obtain
$$\left|\int_0^b e^{-iwt} dt\right| = \left|\frac{2}{w}\right|\cdot\left|\sin(wb/2)\right|$$
For fixed $w$ and $b \to \infty$, the first factor on the right hand side is constant, but the second factor oscillates in the range $[0,1]$. Therefore,
$$\lim_{b \to \infty}\left|\int_0^b e^{-iwt}dt\right|$$
does not converge. Consequently, neither does
$$\lim_{b \to \infty}\int_0^b e^{-iwt}dt$$
which means that the improper integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-iwt}dt$$
does not exist.

Comment: Got it.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The complex exponential function is periodic/oscillatory.  The integral won't converge for more or less the same type of reasoning that, for example, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to+\infty} \sin x$ doesn't exist.