# Fourier series of Heaviside step function?

Tags: analysis, exponential-function, fourier-series, trigonometric-series, step-function

Let us say we have the Heaviside unit step function $\Theta(t-t^\prime)$. I want to calculate its Fourier series
$$
\Theta(t-t^\prime)=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n,m}\Theta_{\omega_n,\omega_m}e^{-i\omega_n t}e^{-i\omega_m t^\prime}\, ,
$$
where $\omega_n=\frac{2\pi}{T}n$. So (according to my understanding) I have to execute the following integral
$$
\Theta_{\omega_p,\omega_l}=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tdt\int_0^Tdt^\prime \Theta(t-t^\prime)e^{i\omega_p t}e^{i\omega_l t^\prime}\, .
$$
The unit step function affects the integration boundaries, such that 
$$
\Theta_{\omega_p,\omega_l}=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tdt\int_0^tdt^\prime e^{i\omega_p t}e^{i\omega_l t^\prime}\, .
$$
I calculated this integral for four different cases of $(p,l)\in \{(0,0),(p,0),(0,l),(p,-p)\}$ because all other cases are $0$. I get the following result
$$
\Theta_{\omega_p,\omega_l}=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tdt\int_0^tdt^\prime e^{i\omega_p t}e^{i\omega_l t^\prime}=
\begin{cases}
&\frac{1}{2}\, , \quad &p=l=0\\
&-\frac{i}{\omega_p}\, , &l=0\neq p\\
&\frac{i}{\omega_l}\, , &p=0\neq l\\
&\frac{i}{\omega_p}\, , &p=-l\neq 0\, .
\end{cases}
$$
And then I plug it into the sum and get the following result
$$
\Theta(t-t^\prime)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{T}\sum_{n\neq 0}\frac{1}{\omega_n}\left(e^{-i\omega_n t^\prime}-e^{-i\omega_n t}+e^{-i\omega_n (t-t^\prime)}\right)\, .
$$
However, I am not sure if that is correct because the step function depends on the difference $t-t^\prime$, so I expected that the Fourier coefficients would also only depend on the frequency differences. Is there a flaw in the calculation?

The second question is: Since depends on the difference $t-t^\prime$, can one just write the Fourier series in the form of
$$
\Theta(t-t^\prime)=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n,m}\Theta_{\omega_n-\omega_m}e^{-i\omega_n (t-t^\prime)}e^{-i\omega_m (t-t^\prime)}\, ,
$$
or something similar, where can read out that it only depends on the time difference??

THX

Comment: It is not a double Fourier series but just a single one.

Comment: Ok, so you mean it is

Comment: $$ \Theta(t-t^\prime)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}\sum_n\Theta_{\omega_n}e^{-i\omega_n(t-t^{prime})} $$?
I'm asking because I have two time variables, so I will have to integrate by $t$ and $t^\prime$?

Comment: The idea is that you just transform $\Theta(t)$ then, you can translate to whatever you want. The point is that, as far as I can say, just the Fourier transform has a meaning. $\Theta$ belongs to a distribution space that is meaningful only under integration sign.Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/fourier-transform-of-unit-step.