# Fourier transform gives rise to the delta function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, dirac-delta, schwartz-space

Let $\varphi$ be a real smooth function with sufficient decay and vanishing mean. Then there exist a functions $\psi$ such that: 
$$\psi(x)'=\varphi(x)$$ then $$\hat{\psi}(\xi) = \frac{\hat{\varphi}(\xi)}{\xi} + \hat{\varphi}(0)\delta(\xi) = \frac{\hat{\varphi}(\xi)}{\xi}$$

Here i am using the following $$\hat\psi(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi(x)e^{-2\pi i x\xi}\:dx$$

Can somehow help me understanding this result? Can someone give me a hint of how to prove this formula? Where does the delta function comes from?

Comment: Can you give more context? For example, which definition of the Fourier transform are you using? Is this in \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: If you are referring to my answer on your post several days ago, this is a well known Fourier transform property. But there needs to be an $i$ in the denominator. Not to mention as stated what you have written is not true because you've ignored the rest of the context of the answer.

Comment: @NinadMunshi i'm sorry, i've new in this fields (distribution theory/Fourier Analysis) and i do not know yet what is necessary and what is not. And yes, it is. I have been searching throw out my books and i've not found a answer, and the answers i read here are somehow poor and i find them not satisfying. If you could somehow, help me or recomend me some book i would appreciate it! Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Sure i will edit the question.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/fourier-transform-of-unit-step) and accept my answer if the only confusion you have is a property which you can look up in a table (the standard method of dealing with Fourier transform properties)

Comment: If the relevance of the linked post confuses you, note that $\int f(x) \:dx = f\star H$ where $H$ is the Heaviside function (aka integration is equivalent to convolution with a Heaviside). This means that the Fourier transform of an antiderivative is equal to the product of Fourier transforms of the original function and the Heaviside.

Comment: @NinadMunshi omg thank you soo much, this is what i needed. Not forcing the answer with the delta fucntion but where actually if comes from, it is as simple as the convulution with the heaviside, thank you so much!