# Fourier transform Cauchy principal value distribution

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory

I would like to compute the Fourier transform of the Heaviside function.
To do this, I want to use the fact that :
$$ F(vp \frac{1}{x}) = -2i\pi H+i\pi $$
where $F$ is the Fourier transform operator and $H$ is the Heaviside step function.

I know that this expression is correct but my problem is that I don't know how to find the correct expression of $F(H)$ from there.

Here is what I get :
$$2i\pi H = F(vp\frac{1}{x})+i\pi \Leftrightarrow F(H)=-\frac{1}{2i\pi}F\bigg(F(vp\frac{1}{x})\bigg)+\frac{1}{2}\delta$$
where delta is the dirac distribution.

I know the correct final expression is:
$$F(H)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}vp\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\delta$$

But I don't really see how to obtain this final expression.

Comment: You might be interested in reading [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/fourier-transform-of-unit-step/4111722#4111722).

Comment: The Fourier inversion theorem is the most important theorem of Fourier analysis ... you should learn the basis before trying to compute difficult Fourier transforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the Fourier transform of both sides of $F(vp \frac{1}{x}) = -2i\pi H+i\pi.$

Then use the fact that $F(F(f(x))) = [2\pi]f(-x)$ (whether the factor $2\pi$ is there or not depends on your exact definition of the Fourier transform).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I was expecting something like this but is the following defintion always true ?$$F(F(f(x)))=[2\pi]f(-x)$$
Can you explain (or point to a good reference) where it comes from ?

Comment: It's a generally valid theorem. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Invertibility_and_periodicity) it is written as $\mathcal{F}^2=\mathcal{P},$ where $\mathcal{P}$ is defined by $(\mathcal{P}f)(x)=f(-x).$ The Fourier inversion theorem is derived from this, and this can be derived from the Fourier inversion theorem.